# UberSvn Remote access to Repository

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, repository, tortoisesvn, ubersvn

I just installed uberSVN on my Windows computer.  I created a repository and am able to access it on my local machine. How would I go about accessing this repository from another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine you're on needs to be able to find the server and that might depend up DNS.

From a Windows command line on the server, type `ipconfig`. It should show you the IPv4 address of the server. On your local machine, use the URL `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/svn/<repo>` where `xx.xx.xx.xx` is the IP address of the Subversion server and `<repo>` is the name of your Subversion repository.

You can talk to your network guys about configuring DNS, so your Subversion server has an actual name instead of just an IP address. You can also edit the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file on the local Windows machine to give your Subversion server a name. Let's say the IP address of the Subversion server is 10.1.0.34 and your repository is `foo`, you could type in:

```
svn co http://10.1.0.34/svn/foo/trunk foo-trunk
```

Or you can edit the `` `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts `` file on your local Windows PC like this:

```
10.1.0.34       svnserver
```

And then use:

```
svn co http://svnserver/svn/foo/trunk foo-trunk
```

Answer (score 0):

if your machines are in the same network, use your machine ip address as the svn server host([URL to repository in torttoise](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86dd495970b-pi)).

Answer (score 0):

The url given for remote access is displayed when you setup a repository in uberSVN (or you can find it from the repository tab afterward).

It's usually http://your.ip.address:9880/reponame